# Communication and parameters view of Layer2/Layer3 in Android based device

Tags: android, mobile, network-protocols, mobile-devices

Is it possible to view layer2/layer3 communication and parameters betweeen network and handset in Android based device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your device is based on qualcomm chipset.